# Testing function call with elvis operator with Mockito in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, elvis-operator

I am trying to test a Service for a spring boot application i am writing in Kotlin and I ran into the following problem:

When trying to test `getPerson(uuid: UUID)` which calls my PersonRepository (which is mocked with Mockito) internally the exception which comes after the function call on the repository is always thrown.

Is there a way to work around this? Or should I handle the throwing of the exception differently?

**PersonServiceTest**

```java
@Test
fun getPersonTest() {
    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
    personService.getPerson(uuid)

    val uuidArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(UUID::class.java)
    verify(personRepository).findByUuid(uuidArgumentCaptor.capture())
}
```

**PersonService**

```java
fun getPerson(uuid: UUID): Person = personRepository.findByUuid(uuid) ?: throw PersonException("not found")
```

Comment: Does the `#getEmployee(UUID)` method of your personService already call the `findByUuid(UUID)` method of your repository? If so you'd need to specify a return value on the mock otherwise the mock returns `null` which causes the elvis expression to throw the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify what happens if findByUuid is called. Right now it returns null.

```
Mockito.`when`(personRepository.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(myFakePerson)
```

In general it might be better to use [mockk](https://mockk.io/) with Kotlin. There you can specify to return default values for all mocked functions of an object. e.g.: `val personRepository = mockk<PersonRepository>(relaxed = true)`

Comment: thank you! I switched to Mockk and it is a lot less of a pain to get it to work!